# Conditional constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, glpk, docplex

I am solving in R using GLPK a classical optimization problem:

```
min c*x 

s.t. Ax<=b
```

Where x is my vector of variables, c is a vector of constants, A is the constraints matrix and b is the constraints vector.

Now my professor wants me to add the constraint that the positive terms in x must sum to 1 and the negative terms to -1.

To simplify things I though to implement it using the constraints

```
sum((x)_+) = 1
```

and

```
sum(x) = 0
```

I do not have much experience with R and I do not know which solvers allow me to write sum((x)_+) = 1 as a conditional constraint. I cannot use GLPK of course can someone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a variable splitting technique. The formulation is

```
  xplus[i] - xmin[i] = x[i]
  xplus[i]*xmin[i] = 0   (make sure one of them is zero) 
  xplus[i], xmin[i] >= 0
```

Some solvers can handle this as is. GLPK is not one of them.
Luckily the model can be linearized as:

```
  xplus[i] - xmin[i] = x[i]
  xplus[i] <= M*b 
  xmin[i] <= M*(1-b)  
  xplus[i], xmin[i] >= 0
  b ∈ {0,1}
```

Here `M` is bound on x:  `-M <= x <= M`. This is a constant. `b[i]` is a binary variable.

Then your additional constraints are:

```
  sum(i, xplus[i]) = 1
  sum(i, xmin[i]) = 1
```

And, of course, you should talk to your professor if you don't understand the assignment.

Comment: thank you for your answer, what solver do you suggest to use?

Comment: I don't. The answer depends on many things I don't know. Again. talk to your professor.

Comment: I wish I could ask my professor but he is convinced that I can do it using linear constraints which on the contrary I am 100% sure that it cannot be done.

Comment: Well, I showed you a nonlinear and a linear model. There is some confusion here.